# how can we treat non linear predictors (variables ) in logistic regression using R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science

How can we treat non linear predictors (variables ) in logistic regression using R? I have heard about Logistic Regression with regression splines can any one tell how to use it with example?

Comment: [DataScience SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) might be of help

Comment: can you plot the distribution of the regressor? Some descriptive statistics would help. Also, since this is statistics related you may get the most help in CrossValidated Stack Exchange. Normalizing the data, between say, 0 and 1 may solve your problem.